# android, Is this a right way of using MyLocationOverlay for getting user location to send it to server...?

Tags: android, location, mylocationoverlay

I am new to android. I have learned about MyLocationOverlay. It can get user location and draw a blue point on that location. I want to get user location and send it to server. Is it possible by using MyLocationOverlay to get user location. If it is, then is this a right way of getting user location using MyLocationOverlay...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible by using MyLocationOverlay to get user location.

Yes, you can call `getMyLocation()`. However, as with `getLastKnownLocation()` on `LocationManager`, this may be `null`.

> If it is, then is this a right way of getting user location using MyLocationOverlay...???

Personally, I would rather use `LocationManager` directly, so I have more control over how that location is determined.